# How to use regex lookahead and match the previous string / character class

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use negative look ahead to match a number if it doesn't precede a `%` sign.

`\d+(?!%)` .
`8989%` .
//matches 898, but not the 9% .
I'd like it to match 8989 as a whole.

Also is it possible use negative look ahead with matching a whole character class or more complex regex?
`[\d.+](?!%)` .
`\d+(\.\d{1,2})?(?!%)` .
Which would match decimals not preceding a `%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\d+(?!%)` pattern matches one or more digits, and grabs `8989` in `8989%` at first, but the `(?!%)` negative lookahead fails that match, and the engine, seeing the `+` quantifier, starts backtracking. It discards the last `9` from the match buffer and retries the `(?!%)` lookahead that succeeds as `898` is not followed with `%` symbol.

You may use

```
/\d+(?![\d%])/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HuzydY/2)

The `(?![\d%])` negative lookahead will fail the match if 1+ digits is followed with any digit or `%` char, and thus will not return partial matches of 1+ digits that are followed with a `%` symbol.